# Create dynamic amount of selectable checkboxes with dynamic variables

Tags: reactjs

This is a standard working checkbox:

```
const [myValue1, setMyValue1] = React.useState(true);

<InputCheckbox
 label="Registry"
 value={myValue1}
 onChange={(value, name) => {
 setMyValue1(value);
 console.log(`${name}:${value}`);}}
/>
```

Now I create a lot of checkboxes like this:

```
{someTools.map(({ title }) => (
    <>

    <InputCheckbox
     label={title}
     value={false} <- Current Placeholder
     onChange={(value, name) => { ...? }}
    />

))}
```

As you can see, in the current state, I can not check or uncheck my checkboxes because I am missing the **const [myValue / setMyValue1]** for every checkbox in my .map function.

How can I dynamically create those variables and use them in my **onChange** function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each tool's title is unique, i'd store the checked values in an object like this:

```
{ [title]: <isChecked> }
```

Further assuming that we already know tools when rendering (we don't fetch them in this function), the `useState` call could look like this:

```
const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(
    Object.fromEntries(someTools.map(({title}) => [title, false]))
);
```

`false` being the initial checked value. (If you fetch the tools in this component, you should initialize `useState` with `{}`)

Last but not least, the JSX would look like this:

```
someTools.map(({title}) => 
    <InputCheckbox
        key={title}
        label={title}
        value={checked[title]}
        onChange={() => setChecked({...checked, [title]: !checked[title]})}
    />
)
```

Comment: thank you kenny. you helped me so much. makes sense!